# Regex expression for parsing of dynamic commands

Tags: regex

I'm writing a simple parser.

Given the following sentence:

```
Hello, how are you @resolve[obj.name] @resolve[obj.surname].
```

With the following expression, I am able to match the above sentence parts that I later evaluate:

```
\@((lookup|resolve|count|href|currencify)\[(.*?)\])
```

However, I'd also be able to recursively match groups, such as the following sentence:

```
Hello, how are you @resolve[obj.name], I hope you have a wonderful @lookup[@resolve[obj.time]].
```

Notice the `@lookup[@resolve[obj.time]]`

The above expression doesn't quite evaluate well, as it matches the `@command[` and the first closing square bracket `@command[@another[obj]` So I'm "almost" there.

How can I recursively extract matches, such that it correctly recognizes the first `[` and the last `]`, then the inner `[` `]`.

If you could please modify my existing expression.

Comment: maybe this? `\@((lookup|resolve|count|href|currencify)\[(.*?)\])(?!\])` See demo: https://regex101.com/r/ZZFtKA/1

Comment: Or https://regex101.com/r/a6MfZT/1

Comment: True regular expressions cannot handle recursion. In practice the most common regex library has been extended until they can, but it'll probably be better to use another approach?

Comment: It depends on the tool or language. With PCRE for example you can recurse the first subpattern `@(?:lookup|resolve|count|href|currencify)(\[(?:[^][]++|(?1))*])` https://regex101.com/r/6jryM1/1

Comment: Indeed; I'm not sure it's a good idea, though. For one thing, it'll give you no error messages as to why your expression is not matching

Comment: FYI `@` does not need escaping.